# Passing values from view to controller without using form/fields

Tags: php, mysql

How to pass value from view to controller without using form/fields? I mean send value from view to controller via link.

View:

```
<?php foreach ($languages as $lang) { ?>
     <li>
       <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/box/<?php echo $template_data['box_id']?>/<?php echo $lang['language_name']?>"></a>
     </li>
 <?php } ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function passby($page) {    
    $uri = 'admin/'.$page;
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('admin/navigation');
    $this->load->view('admin/sidebar');
    $this->load->view($uri);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: which MVC framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your specific framework, but in general PHP if you want to pass variables via a link you use parameters on the querystring like this:

```
http://www.example.com/myPage.php?var1=x&var2=y
```

Then in myPage.php you can access them like this:

```
$var1 = $_GET["var1"];
$var2 = $_GET["var2"];
```

You use `$_GET` because the variables were passed on the querystring (i.e. a GET request), as opposed to `$_POST` which you'd use if the variables were submitted via a form.